# Python: why __init__ method sometimes isn't called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a following code:

```
class Spam:
    def __new__(self):
        self.__init__(self)
        print("1", end = " ")
    def __init__(self):
        print("2", end = " ")
        
class Eggs(Spam):
    def __new__(self):
        print("3", end = " ")
    def __init__(self):
        print("4", end = " ")
e = Eggs()
s = Spam()
```

Can someone explain why the result is 3 2 1, i.e. 4 is not printed? Whereas documentation says that

> "In Python the **new**() magic method is implicitly called before the
> **init**() method. The **new**() method returns a new object, which is then initialized by **init**()"

Comment: Your `__new__` methods are being called just fine. The 4 is printed in `__init__`, which is never called because you overrode `__new__` to not actually create an instance. What do you think should be printed with your code snippet above?

Comment: Note from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__): "The return value of __new__() should be the new object instance (usually an instance of cls)."

Comment: to "call" it you shouldn't use inheritance but by passing the `metaclass` attribute to the class "constructor"/declaration (with python 3)

Comment: Silvio Mayolo, sorry for mistake in the topic name. So __init__ is actually called within __new__, by default? and by overriding __new__ I prevented __init__ from being called?

Comment: No, `__init__` is called after `__new__`, *if `__new__` returns an instance of the class*. Your `__new__` methods do not return an instance of the class.

Comment: Also, that's not the documentation. Your quote appears to come from [an unofficial tutorial website](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/magic-methods-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

The code should be as follows in order to work,

```
class Spam:

    def __init__(self):
        print("2", end = " ")
    
class Eggs(Spam):

    def __init__(self):
        print("4", end = " ")

e = Eggs()
s = Spam()
```

You don't write the new() method because Python has already did all the work for you to not write it. If you run my code above you would get the result 4 2.

Comment: 'super().__init__()' call in 'class Eggs(Spam):'  might help.

Answer (score 0):

The `__new__` method must return an instance of the class. Otherwise, init will not be called. The code should work like this.

```
class Spam:
    def __new__(cls):
        #self.__init__(self)
        print("1", end = " ")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("2", end = " ")

class Eggs(Spam):
    def __new__(cls):
        print("3", end = " ")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("4", end = " ")
e = Eggs()
s = Spam()
```

Another issue is that the `__new__` method acts like a static method. So it does not contain `self`.